# R markdown Stargazer: knit to pdf issue: Executed haulted

Tags: pdf-generation, r-markdown, knitr, stargazer

While trying to knit .rmd file to pdf, if code chunks has stargazer function, the file is not knitting to pdf format. I have several tables (both long and short) with combination of regression output via stargazer in latex format but none of them are converting to pdf. I am using MikTeX as LaTeX distribution. I have used following code (as an example)

```
stargazer(pre.ols.sp01SIOI,pre.ols.sp02SIOI,pre.ols.sp03SIOI,pre.ols.sp04SIOI,
post.ols.sp01SIOI,post.ols.sp02SIOI,post.ols.sp03SIOI,post.ols.sp04SIOI,
style = "qje", type = "latex", header=FALSE, title = "Regression Analysis").
```

I am getting the following error.

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit) entering extended mode
>   I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log Paper1.v7_11Jun2020.log.
>   Error: LaTeX failed to compile Paper1.v7_11Jun2020.tex. See 
>   https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In readLines(log) : line 888 appears to contain an embedded nul
>   2: In readLines(log) :
>     incomplete final line found on 'Paper1.v7_11Jun2020.log'
>   3: In readLines(log) : line 888 appears to contain an embedded nul
>   4: In readLines(log) :
>     incomplete final line found on 'Paper1.v7_11Jun2020.log'
>   5: In readLines(log) : line 888 appears to contain an embedded nul
>   6: In readLines(log) :
>     incomplete final line found on 'Paper1.v7_11Jun2020.log'
>   Execution halted

I have followed the debugging tips mentioned on the yihui.org. But still no luck.
I have also tried to assign the stargazer output and then use kable() and still 
it's not working. Moreover, I have tried to using landscape style.

I appreciate any assistance with the issue.

Thanks

Edit: The YAML header

```
title: XXX 
documentclass: article 
date: "r format(Sys.Date(),'%d %B, %Y')" 
output: 
    pdf_document: 
        df_print: paged 
        fig_caption: yes 
        highlight: tango 
        number_sections: yes 
        citation_package: natbib 
        keep_tex: yes 
        bibliography: library.bib 
header-includes: 
-\usepackage{amsmath} 
-\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
-\usepackage{autobreak} 
-\usepackage{setspace} 
-\usepackage{hyperref} 
-\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} 
-\usepackage{caption} 
-\usepackage{babel
-\usepackage{multirow}
-\usepackage{pdflscape}
-\usepackage{dcolumn} 
-\usepackage{rotating}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide your complete YAML header, and a reproducible example? We do not have your objects `pre.ols...`.

Comment: ` title: XXX documentclass: article
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(),'%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    df_print: paged
    fig_caption: yes
    highlight: tango
    number_sections: yes
    citation_package: natbib
    keep_tex: yes
bibliography: library.bib
header-includes:  \usepackage{amsmath}  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{autobreak}  \usepackage{setspace} \usepackage{hyperref} \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}  \usepackage{caption} \usepackage{babel\usepackage{multirow}\usepackage{pdflscape}\usepackage{dcolumn}  \usepackage{rotating}
`

Comment: pre. OLS are named for different OLS model results. It's working fine while kniting in html but not is pdf. If you want I can upload reproducible code in github.

Comment: You saw the missing bracket `}` for the `usepackage{babel}`?

Comment: Apologise for type. Due to character limit, I couldn't include full YAML, I have `}` in original file. Even though the reproducible file is converting to pdf, in my original project file, I keep getting error. Moroever, whenever I am adding` \blandscape` or `float.env = "sidewaystable"` the file isn't converting. I have included the reproducible file here with sample dataset [link](https://github.com/sunmastermind/Volatility-Connectedness). Thanks – @J_F

Comment: works fine for me.

Comment: Any idea what could be the issue from my end? I have tried in different ways but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think you need to pay attention to this error message: "In readLines(log) : line 888 appears to contain an embedded nul". We know neither your code nor your data (please read about [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2706569)!), but it looks like you're reading a file that contains a `nul` character where it should not.